# How to optimise running and weight training for complete fitness?

Tags: running

I go to the gym in the morning (1 hour) and run in the evening (<1 hour). My goals are GAINING MUSCLE, INCREASING SIZE and BEING FIT. Since both running and weight are essential components of any fitness regime, I don't want to get rid of either of them.

My gym schedule -

```
Chest, Back, Biceps, Triceps, Shoulder, Legs (1 muscle group each day, 6 days a week).
```

My running schedule -

```
Basic running drills and warm-up, running 2.5kms in 12 mins, vertical jumps and post-running stretches (same everyday).
```

My height - 181.5 cms; Weight - 73 kgs/160 lbs.

- Does my running habit affect my muscle gain?
- Should I modify my schedule for effective results?

Any advice is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to address one misconception first (for people viewing this post in future):

> Since both running and weight are essential components of any fitness regime, I don't want to get rid of either of them.

Running is not the only cardiovascular activity. Variety is the spice of life, and all of the following are great alternatives: rowing, stair-mastery, cross training, cycling, swimming, etc.

---

### Goal: Gain Muscle Mass

You are on a weird bro-split, you could work out more effectively by reducing the number of days you do strength training, upping the weight and focusing on compound movements. By doing compound movements you can hit most muscles twice a week. You are trying to build a shrine without having any good foundations. Focus on spending a year or two building good strength foundations. Look to [5x5 Stronglifts](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/) to begin and then move onto something like [IceCreamFitness](https://www.muscleandstrength.com/workouts/jason-blaha-ice-cream-fitness-5x5-novice-workout) or [PPL](http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=149807833). **You will gain muscle mass on all of those routines provided your diet is adjusted accordingly.**

### Goal: Increase Size

**Height? Not possible**, your genetics have already decided what height you will be. If you want to **appear** "bigger" read the paragraph above about increasing muscle mass.

### Goal: Be Fit

Cardio/Conditioning is important, and contrary to (bro)science: Cardio does not kill gains. **[It does effect those at the pro/elite end of the spectrum of bodybuilding but most people can happily do both and end up looking good and being fit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/wiki/faq#wiki_does_cardio_impair_muscle_gains.3F)**.

Running is nice, but as I said, look towards other ways to exercise. There is a well established [basic running progression](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3TYR3d9S1s1dFpwa3E4NmZfOW8/view) that you would get from any PT which is:

1. Run 3 miles every other day, 3-4 days per week
2. Add additional days per week until you run 3-5 miles, 5-7 days per week
3. Gradually increase the mileage of every 3rd or 4th run
4. Add Runs of Quality (higher intensity workouts) 1-3x per week
5. Add secondary runs (doubles) to your schedule
6. Increase the duration of your secondary runs

If you want to add running training tailored towards explosive power then look towards doing interval training (lots of posts online about this). **Your running schedule is fine**.

Finally, your goal for running (be fit) isn't a good one. Pick a time (5 min mile), distance (complete a 10k run) or event (Spartan/tough mudder/marathon) and have that as your goal so you can tailor your running plan to meet it.

Answer (score 0):

Cardio and strength training counteract each other a bit. As long as you aren't running too much, it shouldn't affect your results too much as long as you are eating more calories to counteract the calorie burn from the extra cardio work.

I think your gym schedule should be changed to be more effective for a natural trainee. Most bodybuilders who are following a once per week frequency for each muscle group aren't natural (ie PEDs). For naturals, muscle protein synthesis is the most important factor in muscle gain for the most part. MPS is only elevated post training for 36 hours, meaning training each body part at least 2 times per week is more effective. The most effective would be 3 times per week, but that can be hard to recovery from. You can read more about maximizing protein synthesis here: http://mmfitstrong.com/maximizing-protein-synthesis-part-1/

Comment: "Most bodybuilders who are following a once per week frequency for each muscle group aren't natural" Fancy backing that up with some evidence?

Comment: Only anecdotal due to most athletes claiming no drug use to not forfeit sponsorships. You can read about the relationship a little here http://www.bodyrecomposition.com/muscle-gain/training-frequency-for-mass-gains.html/ It's a good discussion from Lyle Mcdonald, a respected figure in the industry for many years now.